# How to return result from delegate that performing in thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How to return result from delegate that performing in thread?
My method:

```
public TR Calculate(Func<T,TR> method, T opr)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => method(opr));
    t.Start();
    return (result of performing of method);
}
```

If it isn't clear for understanding, please give me advice for improving my question. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Thread` rather than `Task.Run`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay i dont think so, but it is my task, so i dont have a choice

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay in these example is defined method, i have only this Func<T,TR> method as parameter

Comment: sdvdsvsv capturing a variable within the context is the solution to your issue as @JohnathanBarclay stated. Regardless of the parameter of your method.

Comment: @ I agree. Thanks